# Python: 'StandardScaler' object has no attribute '_validate_data'

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, standardization

I recently updated my sklearn. However, since the upgrade I'm getting the error "'StandardScaler' object has no attribute '_validate_data'". The following is a snippet of the code:

```
Xs = pd.DataFrame([[10,20], [20,30], [30,40], [40,50]])
scalerx = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
scalerx.fit(Xs)
```

Comment: Please, provide full code. Thanks.

Comment: Furthermore, tell us your scikit-learn's version.

Comment: Finally, check your code. Why does `scalerx` become `scalex`?

Comment: version is 0.23.1. This code itself gives the "Attribute error". Made the change 'scalerx' to to the code. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can scale the data frame using

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

Xs = pd.DataFrame([[10,20], [20,30], [30,40], [40,50]])
scalerx = StandardScaler()
X = scalerx.fit_transform(Xs.values)
```

Comment: Issue resolved automatically.. Restarting the machine once after upgradation of the library did the job. Thanks all! :)